# How to apply a SCNAction & An Impulse Force to a SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scnnode

Hey I have a ball that gets moved by a force-applied. What im trying to get it to do is basically have the causal effect of gravity acting upon it while its moving through the air to its destination. basically when the "move to" action is playing gravity does not take affect so instead of slowly falling down to the ground it instead moves to its final position then it just falls straight down when the "move to" action stops. do to the gravity in the scene.

Im trying to get the ball to be thrown in an arc and land on the target?

Code:

```
                   func CreateBall() {
    let BallScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Footballs.dae")
    Ball = BallScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Armature", recursively: true)! //the Amature/Bones
    Ballbody = BallScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Ball", recursively: true)!

    let collisionCapsuleRadius3 = CGFloat(0.01) // Width of physicsBody
    let collisionCapsuleHeight3 = CGFloat(0.01) // Height of physicsBody
    Ball.position = SCNVector3Make(Guy.position.x, Guy.position.y, Guy.position.z)
    Ball.scale = SCNVector3Make(5, 5, 5)
    Ball.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0) // x,y,z,w

    Ball.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape:SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNCapsule(capRadius: collisionCapsuleRadius3, height: collisionCapsuleHeight3), options:nil))
    Ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Ball.physicsBody?.friction = 1 //
    Ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0 //bounceness of the object. 1.0 will boounce forever
    Ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1 // ability to rotate
    Ball.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    Ball.physicsBody?.rollingFriction = 1
    Ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BitmaskCollision4
    Ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BitmaskCollision3 //| BitmaskCollision2
    Ballbody.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BitmaskCollision2 | BitmaskCollision3 | BitmaskCollision//| BitmaskCollision2

    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(Ball)
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(Ballbody)


    }
    CreateBall()
```

now this is where the magic happens:

```
                   scnView.scene!.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -9.8, z: 0)

                    let location = SCNVector3(Guy2.presentationNode.position.x, 0.0, Guy2.presentationNode.position.z + Float(50) )
                    let moveAction = SCNAction.moveTo(location, duration: 2.0)
                    Ball.runAction(SCNAction.sequence([moveAction]))


                    let forceApplyed = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 100.0 , z: 0.0)
                     Ball.physicsBody?.applyForce(forceApplyed, atPosition: Ball.presentationNode.position, impulse: true)
```

Comment: You should really only move nodes by either using actions on a Kinematic body, or physics on a Dynamic body. But not combining the two. Are you trying to get your ball to be thrown in an arc and land on a target?

Comment: Yes that exactly what im trying to do :)  @JamesP   See I can apply a force to the object and launch it either left, Right, Back, Foward, Up, Down. But then itll just be launched in that direction it won't go to a specific point target

Comment: I did this the other day, I don't have the code in front of me right now (I can post it when I do), but I adapted the `BallisticVel` function from this link: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/248788/calculating-ball-trajectory-in-full-3d-world.html

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at it thanks @JamesP

Comment: Its a little difficult to translate into swift but most i just don't know what exactly it does. Hopefully you code when post ti will explain everthing @JamesP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining SCNActions and physics doesn't work, you need to use one or the other. Using physics you can calculate the exact force needed to propel your node to a target.

I have adapted a solution for Unity [found here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/248788/calculating-ball-trajectory-in-full-3d-world.html) and utilised an [SCNVector3 extension](https://github.com/devindazzle/SCNVector3Extensions) that makes some of the calculations much easier.

Basically you pass in an `SCNNode` that you want to throw, an `SCNVector3` for the target and an `angle` (in radians) that you want the node to be thrown at. This function will then work out the force required to reach the target.

```
func shootProjectile() {
    let velocity = ballisticVelocity(ball, target: target.position, angle: Float(0.4))
    ball.physicsBody?.applyForce(velocity, impulse: true)
}

func ballisticVelocity(projectile:SCNNode, target: SCNVector3, angle: Float) -> SCNVector3 {
        let origin = projectile.presentationNode.position
        var dir = target - origin       // get target direction
        let h = dir.y                   // get height difference
        dir.y = 0                       // retain only the horizontal direction
        var dist = dir.length()         // get horizontal distance
        dir.y = dist * tan(angle)       // set dir to the elevation angle
        dist += h / tan(angle)          // correct for small height differences
        // calculate the velocity magnitude
        let vel = sqrt(dist * -scene.physicsWorld.gravity.y / sin(2 * angle))
        return dir.normalized() * vel * Float(projectile.physicsBody!.mass)
}
```

It is also important to set the `damping` of the physicsBody to 0, otherwise it will be affected by air resistance.

I’m not going to pretend to know exactly how this works, but Wikipedia has articles that explain all the maths behind it.

**UPDATE**

Since using the code above I've noticed it doesn't always work, especially when the heights of the origin and target are different. From the same forum this function seems more reliable.

```
func calculateBestThrowSpeed(origin: SCNVector3, target: SCNVector3, timeToTarget:Float) -> SCNVector3 {

    let gravity:SCNVector3 = sceneView.scene!.physicsWorld.gravity

    let toTarget = target - origin
    var toTargetXZ = toTarget
    toTargetXZ.y = 0

    let y = toTarget.y
    let xz = toTargetXZ.length()

    let t = timeToTarget
    let v0y = y / t + 0.5 * gravity.length() * t
    let v0xz = xz / t


    var result = toTargetXZ.normalized()
    result *= v0xz
    result.y = v0y

    return result
}
```

Comment: also Im getting alittle error on  'var dir = target - origin' It says Binary operator '-' cannont be applied to two 'SCNVector3' operands @James P

Comment: You need to include the SCNVector3 extension (linked above) in your project.

Comment: is there a way to calculate its direction aswell like it can determine how much power it needs but what about what direction it need to throw it in like this much left or right. @James P

Comment: i think it has something to do with ' dir.y = 0                       // retain only the horizontal direction
            var dist = dir.length()         // get horizontal distance'

Comment: That's what it does, it will give you back an SCNVector3 with the correct force on x,y and z. If you apply that force to the node it will go in the direction of the target.

Comment: ok Im just a little confused because i basically set up a target 50 feet forward and 50 feet to the left and the ball just throw its forward but the ball didn't move left or right so lol. can you help me out. because instead of the ball being 50 feet to the left when it lands which is where the target is. Instead its 50 to right from the target where its original horizontal value was so it basically just through the ball forward and not on a slant. does angle/radians mean left and right? should i pass it the same value is the left/right position of my target?   @James P

Comment: I've added another function that works better for me, the other didn't seem to work in all circumstances.